# Where can I buy a finished mobile camera module?

Tags: camera, mobile, system-on-chip

I am interested in buying a really small camera module for one of my projects. I know I can buy some iPhone/Samsung camera replacements on Ebay. But I have no information on their connectors and interfacing mechanisms.

Does anyone knows of a merchant/vendor/manufacturer of a complete camera on chip system with the lens and datasheet that gives examples on how to interface with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8667
which has a full datasheet on the site.

Also, most electronic distributors such as mouser or digikey will have datasheets of all the products they sell. For example, all the cameras [here](http://www.mouser.com/_/?Keyword=omnivision&FS=True) have datasheets.

A good example to use to look for how to interface to camera modules is the CMUcam source files: http://www.cmucam.org/, which is an open-source computer vision module using the Omnivision cameras (the CMUCam4 uses the OV9665, the CMUcam 5 uses the OV9715). Take a look at the source files to see how they read from the cameras.

Comment: i have seen this one. But it is too expensive for the quality it provides. Those days with full HD and high frame rate, this chip is outdated (earliest commnets date back to 5 years ago or so). I am looking for the guys who actually make these stuff for a living - not for a hobby.

Comment: If you mean buying them from the manufacturer then you will need to have a pretty good project proposal and estimated units before they will even entertain selling to you.